# I would like to translate a default value in webform

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, translation, drupal-webform

I am new in Drupal7. I would like to know, how is it possible to translate the default value in a webform. I can translate the label but I can't translate the dafult value for subject field. 
Please has someone any solution of that?

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding you right, you want to translate the subject default value of a field, you have in a webform.

Try doing a hook_form_alter on the form, and then set the default_value element of the subject field to t($default_value), where $default_value is the value of the default_value element of the form array. That should allow you to translate it.

Without more information thats the best i can offer.